# Variant Id in search.json.liquid file in shopify

Tags: shopify

I need to pass variant id in search.json file in shopify as I am using to add products through variant id in search.autocomplete.liquid file. I have checked they are using variables to call the product 'title, url & thumbnail' in loop as mentioned in the below code. Is there any way to create variable for 'variant id'.

```
{% layout none %}    
{% assign product_cunt = search.results_count  %}    
{% paginate search.results by product_cunt %}   
 {% capture results %}    
   {% for item in search.results %}    
     {% assign product = item %}    
     { "title"    : {{ product.title | json }},   
       "url"      : {{ product.url | within: product.collections.last | json }},    
       "thumbnail": {{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'thumb' | json }},    
       "variant"  : (I need to add variant id variable here)    
     }    
     {% unless forloop.last %},
   {% endunless %}   
  {% endfor %}    
 {% endcapture %}    
{% endpaginate %}    

{ "results_count": {{ search.results_count }},    
  "results": [{{ results }}]
}
```

Thanks very much for looking into this.

Comment: Welcome. Please keep track of code format in your questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of it mentioned below If anybody has same concern.

just need to get the first available variant's ID, you should be able to use

```
product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id
```

there to get the ID of the first available variant for that product.